# <html>None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:

Tags: kotlin

I want to do my task, the code from my teacher but mine is always error :

```
<html>None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:<br/>public constructor Grup(id: Int) defined in com.cika.uasmobiledua.model.Grup<br/>public constructor Grup(name: String, label: String) defined in com.cika.uasmobiledua.model.Grup
```

Here's my code:

```
package com.cika.uasmobiledua.model 
import com.google.gson.Gson 
class Grup {
var id = 0
var name = ""
var label = ""
constructor(id : Int){
    this.id = id
}
constructor(name : String, label : String){
    this.name = name
    this.label = label
}
fun toJson(): String{
    return Gson().toJson(this, Grup::class.java)
}
fun fromJson(json : String): Grup{
    if (json.isEmpty()) return Grup()
    return Gson().fromJson(json, Grup::class.java)
}
```

}

Comment: assuming you are calling `fromJson` function, share the json string that is being passed

Comment: What don't you understand about the error? It seems fairly clear to me. How are you trying to construct a `Grup` instance? The error lists the available constructors and their parameters.